# iPadPro rescaling screen necessary?

Tags: ios, ipad

I have an app targeting iPad (no iPhone support).  While I plan to convert it to use autolayout as of now most of the layout is done computationally (IB is not used to build the screens).  The intent is to redo them later.  This is not what my question is about, however (at least, not directly).

I had not planned on targeting iPadPro12.9 but I'm not sure whether I should [or must?] go ahead and do this.  However, I had expected it to rescale automatically.

I use a launch screen storyboard (but no other storyboards).

I'm getting same symptom as shown here:

[(picture taken from another question)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNHf4.png)

Since iPadPro12.9 support is not crucial, at this time my objective is to make it "passable" but I would like for it to work but be scaled to fit the screen. So this question is different from the others I've seen in that respect.

My questions are these:

1) Must the iPadPro12.9 be supported as a requirement for targeting iPad generally?

2) In order to support it, is there an option to have the app scale automatically to fill the screen?

3) Can you provide a simple overview indicating the general direction (e.g., as it now stands, we have computed coordinates for some anchor points on the screen; it there some way of rescaling to fit the screen other than having to recompute these?)  Because we have many screens and want to get this in the store asap, I want to avoid retrofitting with autolayout for a couple months as it will take quite a bit of time.

Thanks for any assistance you can provide.

Comment: @Rahul: there is no need to add edits to questions simply to add bold formatting. If you wanted i/o formatting, e.g. `iPadPro12.9`, then use backticks instead (I am not sure it is needed here anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you targetting `ipad` only or your `deployment device` is `ipad` then your app must support `every ipad` with proper user experience. Your image not set full screen as per your screenshot, it is simple issue of `autolayout`. Just set four constraints like `top,bottom,leading and trailing` with constant `0` from `superview`. That's it!!